# How to build a propensity model when you have only one target class?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python

I have a use case in which I am trying to build a model which predicts most likely customer to invest in commodity (Share market data).

My dataset consists of customers who invest in commodity segment and those who dont.

I want to take all the customers who already invest in commodity segment and from rest of customers I want to find customers who most likely will be investing in commodity.

But how to build a model when training data has only one as target variable and no zero's

My dataset consists of customers from Jan 2019 till today, so I tried to split dataset into train and test based on date, but dataset is reduced to very small number of rows and My organisation wants to give predictions on all customers with zero as target(not investing in commodity)

Comment: The customers that have not yet invested have a 0 label. You could try to get predictions via cross-validation for all customers. Those with zero label but with a high probability are the most probable ones to invest.

Comment: Is this a good way , to train model with a dataset and to use prediction on same dataset?

Comment: This will be applied in a cross-validation form. Therefore, the model will not have seen the samples you are predicting on.